# Manually deleted numpy arrays saved in .npy files on Galaxy23 with Beeware, yield FileExistsError when trying to run again

Tags: python, android, numpy, beeware

My Beeware app generates numpy arrays that I save in `.npy` format in the `Download` folder of my `Galaxy23`. To check if consecutive runs work correctly, before re-running the Beeware app on the phone in developer mode (connected to a PC on windows 11) I manually delete all the `.npy` files with the phone explorer, but then in the next run I get a crash with a `FileExistingError`, although all the `.npy` files are deleted and not seen in the `Download` folder. Manually empting the `Trash` folder does not help. The same problem occurrs running the app directly from the phone installation (not connected to the PC).

To be able to re-run the Beeware app correctly on the `Galaxy23`, I must restart the phone, and then the `.npy` files are generated again correctly. I use `numpy` with `python 3.8.1`
The same problem occurs if I save the numpy arrays in `.txt` format

When I run the same Beeware app on the `Beeware emulator` with the same files and the same folder, the problem does not show up.

Can anyone give me a direction on what I am doing wrong? Any suggestion or hint will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Based on the understanding provided by the answer given by `blackapps` below, I found a simple workaround that works well for me. The idea is the following: whenever I want to delete a file, say `my_file.txt`, I first rename it as `junk.txt`. The MediaStore updates the indexing, so that `my_file.txt` is not indexed anymore. Then I delete `junk.txt`, and I can now recreate `my_file.txt` again. The only file that remains always indexed is `junk.txt`. I tried it and it seems to do the job both manually and programmatically. The delete function looks as follows:

```
path="/storage/emulated/0/Documents/my_file.txt"
junk_path="/storage/emulated/0/Documents/junk.txt"

def delete_file():
    try:
        os.rename(path,junk_path)
        os.remove(junk_path)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Comment: I see you've already received an answer, but for future reference it would be useful if you edited your question to include the full stack trace of the error, and the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Thanks I will. What I could not find is a way to programmatically erase the mediastore indexing with python using beeware, which is criticsal in many app. So at least I understand the problem, but still not have a solution...

Comment: Based on the understanding provided by blackapps, I found a simple workaround described in the UPDATE above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files will have been indexed by the media store.

There are many sloppy file explorers that only delete the file but not the entry in the media store.

As long as they are in the media store you cannot create them again.

Remove the entry in the media store too.

At reboot the media store scans the whole storage so the entries will go away.

Comment: Of course. No file manager will show the files as the files are deleted. It is th MediaStore that keeps entries. So query the MediaStore for uries and then delete() using the uri. Programmatically.

Comment: Thank you again for your helpful response. Now the all thing is clear to me

Comment: Based on the understanding provided by your answer, I found a simple workaround described in the UPDATE above